# How can I substitute a function in an expression in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

Assuming I have an expression in sympy that I can differentiate with variable (e.g. [image]). This is a position expression and I am interested in differentiating it with respect to time to obtain the velocity.  Using the following code:

```
r = sp.symbols('r')
t = sp.symbols('t')
theta= sp.Function('theta')(t)
params = {'r':1,'l':2, 'theta':2*t}
dtheta = theta.diff(t)

xB = r*sp.cos(theta) 
vB = f.diff(t)
```

I am able to obtain the generic form of the derivative for this:

[image]

I am then able to subsitute quantities like 'r' with subs, e.g. `vB.subs({'r':2})`, which yields:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to substitute the $\theta$ with a function of time. E.g. I would like to substitute [image] and obtain the solution to that specific value.

I appreciate I can change the values right at the beginning, but I expect that this should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# substitution dictionary. Note that the keys are symbols/functions
d = {r:1, theta:3.14 * t}
vB.subs(d).doit()
# -3.14*sin(3.14*t)
```

The `doit()` method is going to evaluate the derivative.